# Service Fabric Application PackageDeployment Operation Time Out exception

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

i have service fabric cluster and 3 nodes are created in 3 systems and it is inter-connected. i am able to connect each of nodes. These nodes are created in windows server. These Windows Server(VMs) are on-premises.

Manually i am trying to deploy my package into my cluster/one of nodes, i am getting **Operation Timeout exception**. i have used below commands to execute for deployment.

Service Fabric Power shell Commands:

```
Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage -ApplicationPackagePath 'c:\sample\etc'       -ApplicationPackagePathInImageStore 'abc.app.portaltype'
```

after execute above command it runs for 2 -3 mins and throws **Operation Timeout exception**. My package size is almost 250 MB and approximately 15000 file exist in my package. after that i have passed an extra parameter -TimeOutSec to 600(10mins) explicitly in above command, then it successfully executed and it copied to service fabric imagestore.

```
Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationPathInImageStore 'abc.app.portaltype'
```

after executed Copy-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage command , i have executed above  Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType command to register my in cluster.but it also throws **Operation timeout exception** then i have passed an extra parameter -TimeOutSec to 600(10mins) explicitly in above command, but no luck it throws same **operation timeout exception**.

Just to make sure these operation Timeout issue because of no files in package or not. i have created simple empty service fabric asp.net core app and created package and try to deploy in same server with using above command, it deployed with in fraction of second and it works as smoothly.

Anybody has any idea how to over come service fabric operation timeout issue ?

How to handle the operation timeout issue if the package contains large set of files ?

Any help/suggestion would be very appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If this is taking longer than the 10 Minute default max it's probably one of the following issues:

1. Large application packages (>100s of MB)
2. Slow network connections
3. A large number of files within the application package (>1000s).

The following workarounds should help you.

Add the following settings to your cluster config:

`"fabricSettings": [
      {
        "name": "NamingService",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "MaxOperationTimeout",
            "value": "3600"
          },
        ]
      }
]`

Also add:

`"fabricSettings": [
      {
        "name": "EseStore",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "MaxCursors",
            "value": "32768"
          },
        ]
      }
    ]`

There’s a couple additional features which are currently rolling out. For these to be present and functional, you need to be sure that the client is at least 2.4.28 and the runtime of your cluster is at least 5.4.157. If you’re staying up to date these should already be present in your environment.

For register you can specify the -Async flag which will handle the upload asynchronously, reducing the need for the timeout to just the time necessary to send the command, not the application package. You can also query the status of the registration with Get-ServiceFabricApplicationType. 5.5 fixes some issues with these commands, so if they aren't working for you you'll have to wait for that release to hit your environment.